# How to Select 3 table and show orderby date

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables and I need to select show mean Transaction Bank. How I can do and I need to make query?

1.Deposit

```
`ID_Deposit      DepositBy .    Money .    Slip .    Status .    DateTime  `
     1              Harmonic      200 .     Slip.jpg    Success   10/10/2019
     2              Invicta       200 .     Slip1.jpg   Success   11/10/2019
```

2.Tranfer

```
`Id_Tranfer          Sent .       Money .    Received .    DateTime .    Status  `
     1              Harmonic      200 .     Invicta       12/10/2019     Success
```

3.Withdraw

```
`Id_Withdraw       WithdrawBy .     Money .    Status .    DateTime .  `
     1              Harmonic         200 .     Success      13/10/2019
```

Comment: Can you please mention your expected query result, what so far you have tried

Comment: i need to select all 3 tables and result show orderby DataTime of Transaction

Comment: you can proceed with UNION ALL in MySQL and apply ORDER BY

Comment: Have error #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: Please refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope this is what you are looking for. 
You can't Union Different Columns that's why i changed the alias to `fakename` to make union works.

```
select a.* from(
     Select deposit_by as fakename,money,dtime from Deposit
Union all
     Select sent as fakename,money,dtime from Transfer
Union all
     Select withdrawby as fakename,money,dtime from Withdraw
) as a order by a.dtime desc
```

[Sample Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=8048e86c2cbe007d30c060c609d81c11)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT ID_Deposit IdentityID, 'Deposit' TypeTransaction,DepositBy Person,Money,Slip,NULL Received,Status,DateTime FROM Deposit
     UNION
     SELECT Id_Tranfer IdentityID, 'Tranfer' TypeTransaction,Sent Person,Money,NULL Slip,Received,Status,DateTime FROM Tranfer
     UNION
     SELECT Id_Withdraw IdentityID, 'Withdraw' TypeTransaction,WithdrawBy Person,Money,NULL Slip,NULL Received,Status,DateTime FROM Withdraw
) Z
ORDER BY DateTime ASC
```